# Can Jenkins Pipeline written in Apache Camel DSL

Tags: apache-camel, jenkins-pipeline

Can we write Jenkins Pipeline with any Apache Camel DSL? it would be very nice to have such feature as Camel DSL is good to write such pipeline with less code and more focused.

Comment: I doubt this would be good, you can already write pipelines in groovy for Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The fabric8 team created a set of Jenkins pipeline functions in groovy that you can use in a nice DSL's way. See more at: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library